# Count unique groups within a pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, combinations

I have a data frame of patent numbers and the inventors who invented those patents. For example:

| patent_number | inventor_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 1 | B |
| 2 | B |
| 2 | C |
| 3 | A |
| 3 | B |

I define a team as a group of inventors who produce a patent together. E.g. the team (A,B) produced patent 1, (B,C) patent 2 and again (A,B) produced patent 3. I want to count the number of unique teams. In this case the answer is 2.

What is the fastest way of counting the number of unique teams using python?

I have written this code, but it is very slow when I run it on my entire data set which includes over 6 million patent numbers and 3.5 million unique inventor ids.

```
teams = []

for pat_id, pat_df in inventor_data.groupby("patent_number"):

    if list(pat_df["inventor_id"]) not in teams:
    
        teams.append(list(pat_df["inventor_id"]))

print("Number of teams ", len(teams))
```

I am looking for speed improvements. If you can help me with understand the reasons why they are faster I am always keen to learn about this.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can `groupby` and aggregate as frozenset and count the unique values:

```
df.groupby('patent_number')['inventor_id'].agg(frozenset).nunique()
```

Output: `2`

Interestingly, you can also easily get the number of occurrences of each team with `value_counts`:

```
df.groupby('patent_number')['inventor_id'].agg(frozenset). value_counts()
```

Output:

```
(B, A)    2
(B, C)    1
Name: inventor_id, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

You could go for:

```py
   inventor_data = inventor_data.sort_values("inventor_id")
   inventor_data.groupby("patent_number").inventor_id.sum().nunique()
```

A few explanations:

- Sorting the values is mandatory to avoid symmetries, and consider (A,B) and (B,A) as a single team.
- You can sum the strings "A" and "B" to produce a string "AB" representing the team (A, B)

Comment: Thank you! I have timed your code and the answer given by @mozway above, they are method 1 and you 2. There's appears fractionally faster but you have very slightly different results, do you have any idea why?

Number of teams:  3667014
Time elapsed to count teams method 1 (@Grégoire): 0:00:43.931967
Number of teams:  3666748
Time elapsed to count teams method 2 (@mozway): 0:00:38.515821

Comment: @Joe The set ensures to have unordered groups. Sorting is more computationally expensive (although for 2 values this should be quite minimal). That might be the cause of the time difference. Regarding the results, can you give examples of differences?

Comment: Indeed, I believe the `frozenset` approach from @mozway is cleaner.
Do you have duplicates in your data ? For example, let's consider 3 rows for a given patent, with inventor = ["A", "A", "B"], then the approach #1 would give "AAB", while the approach #2 would give you {"A", "B"}
@JoeEmmens

Comment: I guess it doesn't really make sense to duplicate one person, but we never know ;)

Comment: Btw, better use `agg(''.join)` rather than `sum`. Repeated string concatenation is very inefficient.

Comment: Thanks both for such detail btw. Your right I had a few duplicate inventors for an irrelevant reason, removing them has equalised the counts. This site is the best.